# Data binding to the Kendo Grid did not work (Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoGrid')

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Please attention to my code.
I passed my object model that there are two items in it but Kendo Grid couldn't show it.

How can I fix this problem?

I've used ASP.NET MVC 5.

**EDIT:** I investigated it further and I could find a JavaScript error. 
Error is:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoGrid'

```
public class ArticleAdminController : Controller
{
    private JahanBlogDbContext db = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext();
    private readonly IArticleRepository _articleAdminRepository;
    public ArticleAdminController(IArticleRepository articleRepository)
    {
        _articleAdminRepository = articleRepository;
    }

    public ArticleAdminController()
        : this(new ArticleRepository())
    {
    }

    // GET: ArticleAdmin
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<Article> list = await _articleAdminRepository.FindAll().ToListAsync();
        return View(list); // list.count = 2
    }

    public ActionResult Editing_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(_articleAdminRepository.FindAll().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This is my view code. when program is run, just grid show with no data!

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model IEnumerable<Jahan.Blog.Model.Article>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Jahan.Blog.Model.Article>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserId);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Summary).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LikeCounter).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.RateCounter).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.IsActiveNewComment).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDate).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ModifiedDate).Width(20);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
            .Create("Editing_Create", "Grid")
            .Read("Editing_Read", "ArticleAdmin")
            .Update("Editing_Update", "Grid")
            .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Grid")
        )
)
<script>
    function parameterMap(options, operation) {
        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in [this page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshooting#javascript-error-that-kendo-widgets-are-unavailable-or-undefined).

If jQuery is included more than once in the page all existing jQuery plugins (including Kendo UI) will be wiped out. Will also occur if the required Kendo JavaScript files are not included.